# Network error trying to access Notes tab but Summary access is fine

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-view

I have started having an issue when I view a contact where I can view/edit the SUMMARY tab without an issue, but when I click on the NOTES tab I get:
Network Error Unable to Reach the Server

But there is no issue with the server (Summary tab has no issues) and no errors that I can find in any error logs.

[image]

Any thoughts on why this is occuring or what could be causing this?

NOTE: This is on Wordpress and I have full wordpress and civicrm admin privileges.

Comment: Does your browser console show anything?

Comment: Nothing in console logs either, but did some more testing and found that a custom WordPress plugin was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out my error was because of a custom WordPress plugin... deactivating the custom plugin, caused the error to go away and everything to work as expected.